# MongoDB GridFS replace/update metadata

Tags: ruby, mongodb, gridfs

I need to update the metadata of a file in GridFS.

I've looked around and found that it is not possible, the only solution is to delete the old record and create a new one with the same id.

How can I create a new record with the same old id?

I have tried to set the :_id => id in the :metadata hash, but it is not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found out that you can access the files_collection, where all the info is saved, and update it, like this:

```
metadata = database.fs.files_collection.find(id_criteria).first[:metadata]
metadata[:value] = { whatever info here }

database.fs.files_collection.find(:_id => id).update_one("metadata" => metadata)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm taking a class & the instructor & notes & examples are horrible.  I was struggling with this.